# Fridgidaire dishwasher making buzzing noise when the motor is running

Tags: dishwasher, noise

I started the dishwasher this morning and everything is normal. Then all of a sudden it starts to make a relatively loud buzzing sound when the motor runs. It stops when it pumps water in and out. The sound reminds me what it sounds like if someone runs a electric drill in another room, and have a little in common with the buzzing sound of a mobile phone when it lays on table vibrating.

The dishwasher runs through the cycle without any problems except for the buzzing sound. Any idea what this might be? I have a feeling it may be something going bad but it happened all of a sudden and does not effect the dishwasher cycle.

Comment: You're probably right in your assessment that something is vibrating and that's what causing the buzzing. Most likely a mount point for _something_ has broken allowing a part to move more than it should. It could be as simple as a wire clip that broke and it's allowing a wire to touch something moving, causing the vibration. Of course, if that's the case, the insulation on the wire won't last long and you'll soon have a short which will, at a minimum, stop the dishwasher, and, at worst, cause a fire.

Answer (score 1):

Dishwashers come with either a washable filter for food particles or a food grinder that reduces food debris to a size small enough to pump out with the waste water. [Examples](https://www.google.com/search?q=dishwasher%20food%20grinder&hl=en&sxsrf=ALeKk00muzjkJDtmnzPVWjN2wwHOte0GHg:1629740083039&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjGzub11sfyAhUzKVkFHYh5B1sQ_AUoAnoECAEQBA&biw=1306&bih=837). If you don't have a washable filter, you have a food grinder.

Occasionally, food particles are durable enough that they don't go quickly and quietly, and you'll have a noise like you mentioned for a few cycles, eventually to stop on its own. If you're handy and you don't feel like waiting, you can access the food grinder and clean it out with a toothbrush, wooden skewer or some other tool. See if you can find an video for your model. Remember to turn off power and water to the dishwasher before disassembly.

Answer (score 0):

The buzzing sound went away just as suddenly as it appeared. A couple of days later in the middle of a cycle the buzz stopped and everything is back to normal. This is a very cheap $350 Frigidaire machine we got after having had super fancy expensive dishwashers that broke after a couple of years. This one has three programs and works just as well or better than those expensive ones. I assumed that it being so cheap was the reason for something to go wrong now, but it looks like this was just a freak incident without an answer to why it happened in the first place.